# Solving $\int_0^{\pi} \sin^2(x) \sin(nx) \sin(mx) dx$ for general $n, m$.

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

It is well known that $\int_0^\pi \sin(nx) \sin(m x)dx = \dfrac{\pi}{2}I(m = n)$. By using an online integration calculator, I found that $$\int_0^\pi \sin^2(x) \sin(nx) \sin(mx) = \dfrac{\pi}{4}I(m=n)$$, when $m,n\neq 1$. (I just tried various $n,m$ and observed this pattern).

I have two questions. First, how can we calculate this integration for general $n,m$ by hands?
Second, what will be the general formula for integrations in the form

$$\int_0^\pi \sin^{2k}(x) \sin(nx)\sin(mx) dx\, ,$$where $k ,n ,m$ are positive intergers.

Comment: Using [Product to sum identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) and [Power-reduction formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formulae)